# SQL display data according to criteria

Tags: sql, database, inner-join, aggregate-functions

A) I have a table of doctors. Each doctor has a unique username, as well as a rating and a specialty. There is a also a table of Surgeries. It contains (among other things)
an attribute with doctor's unique username. It is not unique.

I'm trying to create a table that displays for each specialty. the data:

```
Speciality |   Avg. Rating for Each Speciality | # of surgeries performed by Speciality
```

(first column is just the name of the specialty)

My best so far:

```
 SELECT D.Speciality,t1.Avg, t0.CPT FROM DOCTOR as D 
  INNER JOIN(
    SELECT AVG(AvgRating) as Avg, Speciality
    FROM Doctors as D1
    GROUP BY D1.Speciality 
) as t1 ON D.Speciality=t1.Speciality
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT COUNT(CPT) as CPT, Speciality
    FROM PERFORM_SURGERY AS P
    GROUP BY P.Speciality
    )t0 ON t0.SPECIALITY=D.SPECIALITY
;
```

B) The **doctor** table includes a unique username and a non-unique name. There is also a **Prescription** table. It contains the both the doctor's username and patient's username. 
Now there are 3 more tables that we need. One is a **Req_surgery**, **Surgery** and **Visit**.
**Req_surgery** contains the Doctor's username and a CPT (CPT is unique). The **Surgery** table has a primary key of CPT, and it also contains the cost of the surgery. **Visit** contains the doctor's username and patient's username as well as the cost of the visit.

I want a table with:

```
Doctor Name  | No of Patients Seen | No of Prescriptions written | Total Billing
```

that lists each Doctor's name and the required info.

So far I have:

```
SELECT t1.name, t3.Visits, t2.Prescriptions, t4.money
    FROM DOCTOR as D
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT (FName + LName) as name, Username
            FROM DOCTOR
        ) t1 ON t1.userName=D.username
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT DUsername, COUNT(DateVisit) AS Prescriptions
            FROM PRESCRIPTION
            WHERE MONTH(DateVisit) = $month
            AND YEAR(DateVisit)=$year
        )t2 ON D.Username = t2.DUsername
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT COUNT(DATEVISIT) as Visits, DUsername
            FROM VISIT as V
            WHERE MONTH(DateVisit) = $month
            AND YEAR(DateVisit)=$year
        )t3 ON D.Username=t3=DUsername
```

I didn't even finish because (a) I know what I have is wrong and I don't know how to fix it, and (b) I don't see how to compute the revenue for each doctor.

Doctor has primary key of Username.
Surgeries has primary key of CPT.
Req_Surgery has foreign key of the Doctor's Username (henceforth DU) that references Doctor(Username).

Comment: Can you please share the structures of all your tables, and any foreign key relationships?

Comment: @shree.pat18 sure, but not sure how helpful it will be.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (FName + LName) as name, t3.Visits, t2.Prescriptions, t4.money
    FROM DOCTOR as D
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT DUsername, COUNT(DateVisit) AS Prescriptions
            FROM PRESCRIPTION
            WHERE MONTH(DateVisit) = $month
            AND YEAR(DateVisit)=$year
            GROUP BY DUsername
        )t2 ON D.Username = t2.DUsername
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT COUNT(DATEVISIT) as Visits, DUsername
            FROM VISIT as V
            WHERE MONTH(DateVisit) = $month
            AND YEAR(DateVisit)=$year
            GROUP BY DUsername
        )t3 ON D.Username=t3.DUsername
```

I added grouping by DUsername to get the numbers for each doctor. Also I removed the t1 because in fact it's the same as D